# unable to connect mysql database after working long

Tags: php, mysql

i am not able to connect to MySQL database after working approx 5 hours on MySQL database... is this any cache problem or some type of limit

i get blank page... with static html only

```
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "akhai";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or   trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_select_db($database_localhost);
```

Comment: Can you paste some code please?

Comment: I'm going to guess you're coding in PHP, sounds more like you've got some bad syntax somewhere, like a missing brace

Comment: Some error message would be nice. If you don't get such a message please search stackoverflow for how to add error handling code to your php script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all errors from your script by turning on error reporting (in case it isn't fatal error)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

It will give you your answer

you can also trigger error handler on mysql_connect();

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
```

are you sure your mysql database is up and running?

Comment: it gives unknown database error... but i have that database... i m using that database from phpmyadmin

Comment: are you logging in with same username?

Comment: you're probably out of connection limit. Try using mysql_connect instead and use mysql_connect

Answer (score 0):

Mysql close the connection if there is no actions for a long time .
login in mysql and run:
show variables like "wait_timeout";
you will see the default time.

Setting a longger time of  wait_timeout or reconnect in you php when connection lost.